# Checking If two experiments match

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a noob question for you. I have run two experiments: A and B. Between the two experiments I changed an element which should *not* change the results. I want to check that the results of experiment B do not contradict the results of experiment A.

The results for each experiment are a series of integer counts. I would expect that the results would be approximately normally distributed.

I was thinking of using the following method:

1. Calculate mean and standard deviation of experiment A's results
2. The null hypothesis is that the "independent" variable *did not* affect experiment B
3. Use p-value and the normal distribution confidence interval [erf(n/sqrt(2))] to calculate the probability that a sample as extreme as the sample in B could appear in experiment A
4. Multiply the calculated probability of all samples together to get the p-value

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes there are statistics tests you can use to do the comparison between the two experiments. This answer assumes you have paired data, i.e. the same people or animals or transistors or whatever were used in both experiments.

Assuming your data is not normally distributed, or there is a relatively small number of unique counts per experiment, you could use the [Wilcoxon signed rank test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test). Alternatively, if your data are reasonably normally distributed and you have a relatively large range of counts, you could use a [paired t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test) instead. You will be able to do these tests in the statistical software of your choice.

If the results from the two experiments are statistically significantly different, that suggests that the change between the two is affecting the results.